# Mysql load_file output not complete

Tags: mysql, configuration

I've got a query similar to

```
SELECT Load_file("whatever")
```

and `max_allowed_packet` defaults to `16M`, but the result is somehow incomplete, the ending  is missing (always after a certain length). Is there another variable that needs to be enlarged or something?

Comment: Do you have the setting as `max_allowed_packets` or `max_allowed_packet`?  According to MySQL docs it should be with no s: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry oh, thanks, alas that's just a typo in the question

Comment: @MikulasDite, can you please give the exact query? Perhaps you are storing the file contents to a DB column that doesn't have sufficient length to hold all contents.

Comment: @Abhay Unfortunately I cannot, it's a part of 3rd party API. I only have access to a part of a UNION inside the query. But it might be right, it's certainly worth looking into. Thanks, gonna read the api docs.

Comment: Right @MikulasDite, let us know what you find

Comment: @Abhay The output always has 8192 (2^13) characters or less. Which is weird, mysql has data types of storage of 2 to the power of multiples of eight (for these large ones). Anyway, I think you got it right, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @MikulasDite, I do not think I fully understood it but do you mean that MySQL does not allow storing text larger than 2^13? And I just posted my answer, thanks!

Comment: @Abhay it most definitely does, I was referring to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html. Longtext should support as long text as 2^32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please give the exact query? Perhaps you are storing the file contents to a DB column that doesn't have sufficient length to hold all contents.